# Is it possible for a TCP Sender to send messages to a topic in Apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, mirth

I'm working with Mirth (HL7v2 messages) and Apache Kafka.

Is it possible create a channel with a TCP Sender destination to send messages for a topic in apache kafka?

The image below shows the fields that can be filled

[image: TCP SENDER]

Comment: Kafka has its own TCP protocol. It's not a raw TCP socket

Answer (score 0):

Mirth doesn't have built-in support for kafka. You should be able to use the Java client libraries from any Javascript context in mirth (see the pg 156 of the mirth 3.10 User Guide for configuring Resources to add custom Java libraries to mirth.) A Javascript Writer destination type would probably make sense to use in place of a TCP Sender.